# I'm trying to consume external API and configured the base path and query params

Tags: mulesoft

Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 513: https://host:port/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query?query=SELECT+Caption,IPAddress,NodeID,CustomPollerName+as+Type_Of_Measurement,CustomPollerAssignmentID+as+Node_UDP_ID,CustomPollerID+as+MeasurementID,AvgRate+as+Current_Value,Datetime+FROM%20orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatistics+S+JOIN+Orion.npm.CustomPollerAssignment+C+on+S.CustomPollerAssignmentID+=+C.CustomPollerAssignmentID%20+JOIN+orion.Nodes+N+on+C.NodeID=N.NodeID+where+((CustomPollerID='1b1394d5-73fb-4cca-8c26-f43ae6dafdaa'+and+AvgRate<0)or(CustomPollerID='45004cd8-04cd-4880-93fa-c0ca44eae8c6'+and+AvgRate>0))+and+(HOURDIFF(DATETIME,GETDATE())<=2+and+MINUTEDIFF(DATETIME,GETDATE())>0)+ORDER+BY+DATETIME+DESC

Comment: You need to share the request configuration and product and version so we can understand what are you doing and how to match that to the error.

Comment: Also the complete error message. I'm guessing you replaced the host and port for privacy but now the index position doesn't reflect the real position in the URL.

Comment: host:port- kctacoriont01:17778

Comment: I'm trying to post complete log but i couldn't.